# Buscar un elemento por su id en un array

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy intentando buscar un elemento por su atributo id y luego imprimirlo en el caso 2 del swich en java, pero me marca error!

Aqui el codigo de la clase main.

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int contador = 0;
    int opcion;
    
    Jugador [] jugadores = new Jugador[5];
    
    do{     


        System.out.println("Digite una opcion");
        
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();
        
        switch(opcion){
            case 2:
                
                System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador");
                int id = entrada.nextInt();
                for (int i=0; i<contador;i++){
                    if (id == contador[i].getId) {
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Que se supone que hace `contador[i].getId`? Que esperas que suceda?

Comment: que compare el id ingresado por el usuario, para buscarlo en el array, y después imprimir los datos.

Comment: los getters son métodos, deben ser llamados con paréntesis `contador[i].getId()`, igual edita tu pregunta y **agrega el error que te sale**

Comment: Si la variable `contador` es un `int`, que hasta ahí vale cero según el código que se ve, no puedes hacer `contador[i]` y mucho menos `contador[i].nada_de_nada`. No será `jugadores[i].getId()`? Suponiendo que la clase `Jugador` tuviera un método `getId()` que retorne un entero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David el for esta mal formulado. No entiendo la variable contador.

```
System.out.println("Digite el id del jugador");
            int id = entrada.nextInt();
            for (int i=0; i<jugadores.length;i++){
                if (id == jugadores[i].getId()) {
                   "Accion a Realizar"

                }
            }
```

Como ves he cambiado la variable contador por la función (jugadores.length) la cual devuelve la longitud del array lo que nos permite que el for lo recorra entero. También he cambiado otra vez la variable contador del if ya que no tenia sentido porque tu lo que necesitas es comprobar el id con la información guardada en tu array jugadores, contador no es un array. Y ya faltaría añadir la lógica que tu quieras añadir en tu if. Tambien te recomendarí rellenar el array de jugadores que a lo mejor te sigue saltando error por eso. Mucha Suerte!!